# continuity of two-variable function

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

Is

$$f(x, y) = \begin{cases}|x|^y &(x,y) \neq (0,0) \\ 0 & (x,y) = (0,0) \end{cases}$$ continuous at $(0,0)$?

Intuitively, when $y$ is coming from the negative then $f$ becomes large. So this is not continous. But how can I prove it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose for the sake of contradiction that $f$ is continuous at $(0,0)$. Then given $\varepsilon =1>0$, there should exist some $\delta >0$ such that $|f(x,y)-f(0,0)|<\varepsilon=1$ whenever $d((x,y),(0,0))=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\delta $. But consider setting $0<x<\delta $ and $y=0$; then $d((x,y),(0,0))=x<\delta$, but $|f(x,y)-f(0,0)|=|x|^0=1=\varepsilon$, a contradiction. So $f$ is indeed not continuous at $(0,0)$.

For a more intuitive summary, a function on $\mathbb{R}^2$ is continuous at a point if it is continuous along every path approaching that point. In this case, approaching the origin along the $x$-axis always gives $1$ no matter how close we get, so it can't be continuous at the origin.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x_n\to 0$ be a positive sequence and let $y_n=x_n$. Then
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} f(x_n,y_n) = \lim_{n\to\infty} (x_n)^{x_n}=1$$
since from single variable calculus $\lim_{x\to 0^+} x^x=\lim_{x\to 0^+} e^{x \ln x}=e^0=1$. This shows $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} f(x,y)$ either equals $1$ or it does not exist; and either way, it can't equal $f(0,0)=0$, so the function is not continuous at $(0,0)$.

Actually, it would be simpler this way: for $y_n=0$ and $x_n\to 0$ and positive, we have $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(x_n,y_n) = \lim_{n\to\infty} 1 = 1$.

You could also follow your intuition: taking negative $y$ values and choosing an appropriate $x_n$ which is small enough would make the function approach $\infty$, which would again show that the function is not continuous. (But you would need to pick $x_n$ which is small in absolute value compared to $y_n$.)